# How to change php database setting from form called with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

Title is not to clear but I have been stumped on this for a while now and I cant find anything online.

I have a table in a database being displayed on to the page.

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projects', "root", "");
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from projects WHERE creatorOfProject="'.$username.'"') as $row) {
            $projectName    = $row['ProjectName'];
            $lastEdited     = $row['lastEdited'];
            $projectId      = $row['openId'];

    echo '
                <tr id = "td">
                    <td class="index"><a href="../workspace/index.php?projectId='.$projectId.'" target="_blank">'.$projectName.'</a></td>
//here
                    <td class="index"><a href="../workspace/settings.php?projectId='.$projectId.'" ><img src = "../img/setting.png"></td>
//
                    <td class="index"><a href="../workspace/delete/delete.php?projectId='.$projectId.'"><img src = "../img/delete.png"></a></td>
                    <td class="index"><span id="lastEdited">Last Edited: '.$lastEdited.'</span></td>
                    <td class="index"><span id = "sharedOption">'.$shared.'</span></td>
                </tr>
            ';
```

If you look there is a settings button where when clicked I want to open up a little pop up box (not a separate page or window) with a form in it then be able to update the database from what is user inputs into the form.

I am struggling on how I would call javascript to open display this box and have the information pass through so when the form is submitted I will be able to update the database.

I am not familiar with ajax but I am open to working with it.

Comment: You will need to add a modal window to your page. This is done with a bit of HTML and CSS. Within this window you will need an iframe that points to the page that you want to show. This page will handle all of the form information, validation and submission. This way there is no need for Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax, coupled with a good UI library can do this, and the results should be sufficiently slick (if that matters).

jQuery is a great place to start:

http://jquery.com/

jQuery offers a good abstraction layer that hides away a lot of the browser differences that can make  Ajax (and a lot of javascript) a pain in the neck, plus they have a good UI library on top of that.

An Ajax tutorial is beyond the scope of this response (but there are plenty of resources online), but you will need to re-orient your thinking.  Your javascript page will become your driver, and instead of updating your page via PHP, you'll update your controls from within javascript (on the ajax return).